# Fill in bridge table with query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four tables, the main purpose of these tables is to have a many to many keyword to message relationship. each keyword can have many messages and each message can have many keywords they are related together if the category id matches.

```
CREATE TABLE public.trigger_category
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trigger_category_id_seq'::regclass),
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT trigger_category_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE TABLE public.trigger_keyword
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trigger_keyword_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    category_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT trigger_keyword_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT trigger_keyword_category_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
        REFERENCES public.trigger_category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
CREATE TABLE public.trigger_message
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trigger_message_id_seq'::regclass),
    message text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    category_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT trigger_message_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT trigger_message_category_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
        REFERENCES public.trigger_category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
CREATE TABLE public.trigger_keyword_trigger_message
(
    trigger_keyword_id bigint NOT NULL,
    trigger_message_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT trigger_keyword_trigger_message_trigger_keyword_id_trigger_mess PRIMARY KEY (trigger_keyword_id, trigger_message_id),
    CONSTRAINT trigger_keyword_trigger_message_trigger_keyword_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (trigger_keyword_id)
        REFERENCES public.trigger_keyword (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT trigger_keyword_trigger_message_trigger_message_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (trigger_message_id)
        REFERENCES public.trigger_message (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I manually insert keywords in the `trigger_keyword` table and I manually insert messages in the `trigger_message` table, if they are related then they would get the same `category_id`

Is it possible to write a query that would automatically go through the rows and if a keyword and message have the same `category_id` then it would create all the appropriate rows for the bridge table `trigger_keyword_trigger_message`?

Comment: Your schema does not appear to be completely normalized.  I think you should have separate tables relating messages/keywords to categories.  In general, no, there is no automatic way to do what you want.  Each message/keyword relationship would need to be stored somehow in the bridge table.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with an [Oracle Merge Query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606).

The `USING` clause selects all records to insert, and the `WHEN MATCHED` does to inserts in the bridge table.

```
MERGE INTO trigger_keyword_trigger_message tktm
USING (
    SELECT tk.id tk_id, tm.id tm_id
    FROM
        trigger_keyword tk
        INNER JOIN trigger_message tm on tm.category_id = tk.category_id

) us
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (tktm.trigger_keyword_id, tktm.trigger_message_id)
    VALUES (us.tk_id, us.tm_id)
;
```